# Are Aws Always Free limits per account or per email address/actual AWS Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Are Aws Always Free limits per account or per email address/actual AWS Account?
I couldn't find anything online and am hoping someone with experience can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Free limits per account or per email address/actual AWS Account?

When you first create an Amazon Web Services (AWS) account, you begin with a single sign-in identity that has complete access to all AWS services and resources in the account. This identity is called the AWS account **root user** and is accessed by signing in with the email address and password that you used to create the account.

So the free tier is for the Per AWS account and there is only one root user per AWS account while the rest of the users are all IAM users in this account.

> The AWS Free Tier is automatically activated on each new AWS account.
>   The AWS Free Tier lasts for one year. While the AWS Free Tier is
>   active, you can try many AWS services for free.

[free-tier](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/what-is-free-tier/)

Answer (score 1):

You mention "Aws Always Free limits".

There are two types of limits available in the the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/):

- Some are only valid for the **first 12 months** of the AWS Account
- Some are valid ***every* month** (even beyond 12 months)

The limits for both are calculated for the **AWS Account**.

The limits are intended for people to *try* AWS services. They are not intended to provide free services for production-levle deployments. The limits and allowances might also change in future.